# Structured data tag generation not viewable by Googlebot on Angular SPA app

Tags: angular, seo, single-page-application, googlebot

When live testing a URL on Google Search Console, Googlebot can render a page but my structured data is missing. It is generated in JS via:

```
insertStructuredData(genDataFn: Function): void {
    this.removeStructuredDataElement();

    let script = this.getStructuredDataElement();
    if (!script) {
      script = document.createElement('script');
      script.type = 'application/ld+json';
      script.id = STRUCTURED_DATA_TAG_ID;
      document.head.appendChild(script);
    }

    safeScriptEl.setTextContent(script, scriptFromJson(genDataFn()));
  }
```

When I view the page myself it shows up just fine:

```
<script type="application/ld+json" id="structuredDataScriptTagId" nonce="abcdefg">...</script>
```

But when I view the HTML that Googlebot see on the Live test, this tag is missing from the page. Is this purely a latency issue or could there be anything else impacting this tag's visibility to Googlebot?

Comment: You can never rely on googlebot to execute javascript. The only safe route is to use ssr or ssg for SEO.

Comment: SSR is not an option for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things that you can check:

1. Make sure your json-ld object is valid and doesn't contain errors. You can use the [Rich Results Test tool](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) to validate your implementation.
2. Review the lighthouse report on your website, and make sure that your page is loading on a reasonable time and the json-ld is being included as soon as possible in the DOM when the page loads.
3. [Google Doesn’t Read Unsupported Structured Data](https://www.searchenginejournal.com/google-structured-data-rarely-gives-us-unique-information/389729/#close), so make sure the structured data object you are using is supported by Google, take a look to the [Search Gallery here](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery).

That's basically al you can do, but even then, Google will decide whether to use or not the data defined on your structured-data objects; as they have stated on the official documentation ***[The actual appearance in search results might be different](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/search-gallery)***